# Spark insertInto failure using partition columns of different case. hive bug?

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I am testing use of PySpark's `insertInto()` method for inserting data into an existing table. I have hit upon a problem that I believe to be a consequence of a known bug and am seeking confirmation. I am also wondering if there is a workaround that I do not know of.

I am using Spark v2.2.1:
[image]

and, if this command is to be trusted, Hive v2.1.1
[image]

This code successfully creates a table and inserts data into it:

```
table_name = "default.insert_test"
sqlContext.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s" % table_name)
sql = """
CREATE TABLE %s (col string)
PARTITIONED BY (pcol bigint)
STORED AS PARQUET
""" % table_name
sqlContext.sql(sql)
sqlContext.createDataFrame([('Alice', 1)], ['name', 'age'])\
.write.mode('overwrite').insertInto(table_name)
```

However this code (only difference is the upper casing of the partition column name):

```
table_name = "default.insert_test"
sqlContext.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s" % table_name)
sql = """
CREATE TABLE %s (col string)
PARTITIONED BY (PCOL bigint)
STORED AS PARQUET
""" % table_name
sqlContext.sql(sql)
sqlContext.createDataFrame([('Alice', 1)], ['name', 'age'])\
.write.mode('overwrite').insertInto(table_name)
```

fails on the call to `insertInto()` with error:

> AnalysisException:
>   u'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.ValidationFailureSemanticException:
>   Partition spec {pcol=, PCOL=1} contains non-partition columns;'

I know that I can workaround this problem by using Spark SQL's new CREATE TABLE syntax (see [SPARK-18885 - unify CREATE TABLE syntax for data source and hive serde tables](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18885)) like so:

```
table_name = "default.insert_test"
sqlContext.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s" % table_name)
sql = """
CREATE TABLE %s (col string, PCOL bigint)
USING PARQUET
PARTITIONED BY (PCOL)
""" % table_name
sqlContext.sql(sql)
sqlContext.createDataFrame([('Alice', 1)], ['name', 'age'])\
.write.mode('overwrite').insertInto(table_name)
```

Unfortunately we have clients that have existing tables created using the old CREATE TABLE syntax thus its a scenario that we have to support.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way that I don't know of to use `insertInto()` against
   tables that exhibit this problem?
2. Is [HIVE-14032 - INSERT
   OVERWRITE command failed with case sensitive partition key names](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14032)
   the underlying cause of what I am experiencing?